# How to know which ShaderChunk to replace when extending three.js built in materials with custom shaders?

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader

When extending three.js materials with my own custom glsl shaders using the .onBeforeCompile() method we replace certain parts of the existing material shader code, for example:

```
myMaterial.onBeforeCompile = (shader) => {
  const parseVertexString = /* glsl */ `#include <displacementmap_pars_vertex>`;
  shader.vertexShader = shader.vertexShader.replace(
    parseVertexString,
    parseVertexString + vertexShaderPars
  );
}
```

I got this code snippet from the internet, the part in this I don't understand is how do we know which three.js shaderChunk to replace?

Here in my example we are replacing the "displacementmap_pars_vertex" shaderChunk, but again I am not sure why we are replacing that specific one. And what if we want a custom fragment shader, which shaderChunk should I then choose to replace?

Answer (score 2):

The usage of `Material.onBeforeCompile()` requires a good understand of how the built-in material shaders are implemented. In general, the shader of a material is composed of different shader chunks. You can find this composition for each material in the following directory:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib

For example the file `meshphong.glsl.js` represents the shader of `MeshPhongMaterial`. Depending on what part of the shader you want to change or customized, you have to select a different shader chunk and overwrite it with `Material.onBeforeCompile()`.

Comment: Is there any resources or tips for learning about shaderChunks so I know what shaderChunk I should overwrite for my scenario?

Comment: no, you have to read the source. Some are easier than others. For example, adding lines at the end of the shader would allow you to transform the final `gl_FragColor`. Likewise, adding stuff right above `main` would allow you to (safely) inject your uniforms and variables. 

Many of them operate on one variable, so you can capture those after some number of chunks. Eg different normal chunks do different things to normals but they all transform vec3 normal for example.

Comment: Eg, transforming _some_ shader to grayscale, could be done by looking at the very last chunk in a shader and then adding something after it, or looking for that last }.

Comment: Here is an old experiment exploring what it would look like if you could just provide your own chunks for the `include` logic. There was no reason to have anything other than ShaderMaterial inside the renderer. `onBeforeCompile` is extremely awkward to use.

https://github.com/pailhead/three-refactor-chunk-material/tree/master/src

Comment: It's mine, it's old, but may be worth taking a look:
https://medium.com/@pailhead011/extending-three-js-materials-with-glsl-78ea7bbb9270

Comment: Thank you for the info, so I understand it's a pretty tedious process, and you have to purely understand the source code